# Indoor Atlas: Searching in a Map

Tags: android, search, indoor-positioning-system, atlas

I'm using Indoor Atlas for an educational project based on Android.
I'd like to implement search functionality into a map that I loaded in Indoor Atlas environment, how I can this?
For example I'd like to search  a room of specific, apartment, how  I can implement this searching functionality?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You should mapping the location firstly.
And do test path for making your map more precise.
There is official app of IndoorAtlas, so you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to map your floor using indooratlas app i.e IndoorAtlas MapCreator 2. Then you can record the coordinates using that app and then you can save the coordinates of the rooms/areas in your server and then can fetch and point it on maps after search.

/*
gimal.adobe.appsbee.com.gimbaladobe.Indooratlasmap
16/12/16
sumit-chakraborty
*/
public class IndoorAtlasMap implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter, GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "IndoorAtlasExample";
    private IndoorAtlasCallBack mIndoorAtlasCallBack;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

```
private static final float HUE_IABLUE = 200.0f;

/* used to decide when bitmap should be downscaled */
private static final int MAX_DIMENSION = 1048;

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
private Marker mMarker;
private Marker mMarkerLoc;
private GroundOverlay mGroundOverlay;
private IALocationManager mIALocationManager;
private IAResourceManager mResourceManager;
private IATask<IAFloorPlan> mFetchFloorPlanTask;
private static LatLng latlongfromlistner;

private Target mLoadTarget;
private boolean mCameraPositionNeedsUpdating;
private ArrayList<ListLatlong> latlong;

LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private TextView textViewTitle;
private RelativeLayout rl_custominfo;

public IndoorAtlasMap(IndoorAtlasCallBack mIndoorAtlasCallBack, LayoutInflater inflater) {
    this.mIndoorAtlasCallBack = mIndoorAtlasCallBack;
    this.inflater = inflater;
}

/**
 * Listener that handles location change events.
 */
private IALocationListener mListener = new IALocationListenerSupport() {

    /**
     * Location changed, move marker and camera position.
     */

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(IALocation location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "new location received with coordinates: " + location.getLatitude()
                + "," + location.getLongitude());
        System.out.println("!!!!!!aaa" + location.toString());
          if (mMap == null) {
              // location received before map is initialized, ignoring update here
              return;
          }

          latlongfromlistner = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

            if (mMarker == null) {
                // first location, add marker
                mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlongfromlistner)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(HUE_IABLUE)));

            } else {
                // move existing markers position to received location
                mMarker.setPosition(latlongfromlistner);
        }

          // our camera position needs updating if location has significantly changed
          if (mCameraPositionNeedsUpdating) {
              //Create a new CameraPosition
              mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlongfromlistner, 19.0f));
              mCameraPositionNeedsUpdating = false;
          }
          mMarker.hideInfoWindow();

    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        switch (status) {
            case IALocationManager.STATUS_CALIBRATION_CHANGED:
                String quality = "unknown";
                switch (extras.getInt("quality")) {
                    case IALocationManager.CALIBRATION_POOR:
                        quality = "Poor";
                        break;
                    case IALocationManager.CALIBRATION_GOOD:
                        quality = "Good";
                        break;
                    case IALocationManager.CALIBRATION_EXCELLENT:
                        quality = "Excellent";
                        break;
                }
                MyLog.d(TAG, "Calibration change. Quality: " + quality);
                break;
            case IALocationManager.STATUS_AVAILABLE:
                MyLog.d(TAG, "onStatusChanged: Available");
                break;
            case IALocationManager.STATUS_LIMITED:
                MyLog.d(TAG, "onStatusChanged: Limited");
                break;
            case IALocationManager.STATUS_OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                MyLog.d(TAG, "onStatusChanged: Out of service");
                break;
            case IALocationManager.STATUS_TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                MyLog.d(TAG, "onStatusChanged: Temporarily unavailable");
        }
        }
};


/**
 * Region listener that when:
 * <ul>
 * <li>region has entered; marks need to move camera and starts
 * loading floor plan bitmap</li>
 * <li>region has existed; clears marker</li>
 * </ul>.
 */
private IARegion.Listener mRegionListener = new IARegion.Listener() {

    @Override
    public void onEnterRegion(IARegion region) {
        System.out.println("!!!!!!aaa enter" + region.toString());
        mIndoorAtlasCallBack.hideLoading();
        if (region.getType() == IARegion.TYPE_UNKNOWN) {
            mIndoorAtlasCallBack.showToast("Moved out of map");
            return;
        }
        // entering new region, mark need to move camera
        mCameraPositionNeedsUpdating = true;
        final String newId = region.getId();
        mIndoorAtlasCallBack.showToast(newId);
        fetchFloorPlan(newId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onExitRegion(IARegion region) {
        System.out.println("!!!!!!aaa exit" + region.toString());
        if (mMarker != null) {
            mMarker.remove();
            mMarker = null;
        }
    }




};

public void onCreatePoints(ArrayList<ListLatlong> latlong) {
    this.latlong = latlong;
    if (null != latlong) {
        for (int i = 0; i < latlong.size(); i++) {
            String title = latlong.get(i).getLoc() != null ? latlong.get(i).getLoc() : "adobe";
            mMarkerLoc = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlong.get(i).getLatLng())
                    .title(title)
                    .snippet(String.valueOf(latlong.get(i).getId()))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Sets bitmap of floor plan as ground overlay on Google Maps
 */
private void setupGroundOverlay(IAFloorPlan floorPlan, Bitmap bitmap) {

    if (mGroundOverlay != null) {
        mGroundOverlay.remove();
    }

    if (mMap != null) {
        BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
        IALatLng iaLatLng = floorPlan.getCenter();
        LatLng center = new LatLng(iaLatLng.latitude, iaLatLng.longitude);
        GroundOverlayOptions fpOverlay = new GroundOverlayOptions()
                .image(bitmapDescriptor)
                .position(center, floorPlan.getWidthMeters(), floorPlan.getHeightMeters())
                .bearing(floorPlan.getBearing());

        mGroundOverlay = mMap.addGroundOverlay(fpOverlay);
    }
}

/**
 * Download floor plan using Picasso library.
 */
private void fetchFloorPlanBitmap(final IAFloorPlan floorPlan) {

    final String url = floorPlan.getUrl();
    //saving floor level and floor name
    App.getInstance().getAppPreferences().setFloorId(floorPlan.getFloorLevel());
    App.getInstance().getAppPreferences().setFloorName(floorPlan.getName());
    if (mLoadTarget == null) {
        mLoadTarget = new Target() {

            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onBitmap loaded with dimensions: " + bitmap.getWidth() + "x"
                        + bitmap.getHeight());
                setupGroundOverlay(floorPlan, bitmap);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                // N/A
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable placeHolderDraweble) {
                mIndoorAtlasCallBack.showToast("Failed to load bitmap");
                mIndoorAtlasCallBack.hideLoading();
            }
        };
    }

    if (null != mIndoorAtlasCallBack.getContext()) {
        RequestCreator request = Picasso.with(mIndoorAtlasCallBack.getContext()).load(url);
        final int bitmapWidth = floorPlan.getBitmapWidth();
        final int bitmapHeight = floorPlan.getBitmapHeight();
        if (bitmapHeight > MAX_DIMENSION) {
            request.resize(0, MAX_DIMENSION);
        } else if (bitmapWidth > MAX_DIMENSION) {
            request.resize(MAX_DIMENSION, 0);
        }

     request.into(mLoadTarget);
    }
    mIndoorAtlasCallBack.onSuccessIndoorMapLoad();
}


/**
 * Fetches floor plan data from IndoorAtlas server.
 */
private void fetchFloorPlan(String id) {

    // if there is already running task, cancel it
    cancelPendingNetworkCalls();

    final IATask<IAFloorPlan> task = mResourceManager.fetchFloorPlanWithId(id);

    task.setCallback(new IAResultCallback<IAFloorPlan>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(IAResult<IAFloorPlan> result) {

            if (result.isSuccess() && result.getResult() != null) {
                // retrieve bitmap for this floor plan metadata
                fetchFloorPlanBitmap(result.getResult());

            } else {
                // ignore errors if this task was already canceled
                if (!task.isCancelled()) {
                    // do something with error

                    mIndoorAtlasCallBack.showToast("loading floor plan failed: ");
                    // remove current ground overlay
                    if (mGroundOverlay != null) {
                        mGroundOverlay.remove();
                        mGroundOverlay = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, Looper.getMainLooper()); // deliver callbacks using main looper

    // keep reference to task so that it can be canceled if needed
    mFetchFloorPlanTask = task;

}

/**
 * Helper method to cancel current task if any.
 */
private void cancelPendingNetworkCalls() {
    if (mFetchFloorPlanTask != null && !mFetchFloorPlanTask.isCancelled()) {
        mFetchFloorPlanTask.cancel();
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
    this.mMap = mMap;
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(this);
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
}


public void onDestroyView() {
    mIALocationManager.removeLocationUpdates(mListener);
    mIALocationManager.registerRegionListener(mRegionListener);
    onDestroy();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    mIALocationManager.destroy();
    System.out.println("!!!!!!aaa" + "onDestroyView");
    if (null != mMarker) {
        mMarker.remove();
    }
    if (null != mMarkerLoc) {
        mMarkerLoc.remove();
    }
    mIndoorAtlasCallBack.hideLoading();
}

public void onPause() {
    mIndoorAtlasCallBack.hideLoading();
}


public void onResume() {
    mIALocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(IALocationRequest.create(), mListener);
    mCameraPositionNeedsUpdating = true;
}

public void onIndoorAtlasInit(int map_container) {
    mIndoorAtlasCallBack.showLoading(mIndoorAtlasCallBack.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.loading_msg));
    FragmentManager fm = mIndoorAtlasCallBack.getChildFragmentManager();
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map_container);
    if (mapFragment == null) {
        mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(map_container, mapFragment).commit();
    }
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle(2);
    extras.putString(IALocationManager.EXTRA_API_KEY,
            App.getInstance().getAppPreferences().getApiKey());
    extras.putString(IALocationManager.EXTRA_API_SECRET,
            App.getInstance().getAppPreferences().getSecretkey());

    mIALocationManager = IALocationManager.create(mIndoorAtlasCallBack.getContext(), extras);

    final String floorPlanId = App.getInstance().getAppPreferences().getFloorPlanId();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(floorPlanId)) {
        final IALocation location = IALocation.from(IARegion.floorPlan(floorPlanId));
        mIALocationManager.setLocation(location);
    }

    mResourceManager = IAResourceManager.create(mIndoorAtlasCallBack.getContext(), extras);

    mIALocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(IALocationRequest.create(), mListener);
    mIALocationManager.registerRegionListener(mRegionListener);
}

@Override
public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapinfowindow, null);
    if (marker != null && (marker.getTitle() != null && marker.getTitle().length() > 0)) {
        MyLog.sout("!!!!oninfowindow", marker.getSnippet());
        textViewTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        rl_custominfo = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.rl_custominfo);
        textViewTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
        textViewTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rl_custominfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else{
        return null;
    }
    return (v);
}

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    MyLog.sout("!!!!oninfo", marker.getSnippet());
   LatLng latlng = marker.getPosition();
    Double distance = CalculateDistancex.CalculationByDistance(latlng,latlongfromlistner) ;
    distance = distance*100;
    distance = Double.valueOf(Math.round(distance));
    distance = distance /100;
    if(null !=marker) {
        mIndoorAtlasCallBack.onClickFromInfoWindow(marker.getSnippet(), distance);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Sumit, How can I extract all the waypoints of a region? any sample project related to indoor-atlas except the given one?...